# Add days to JFactory::getDate() excluding Weekends (Sat and Sun)

Tags: joomla-3.x, date

I need to add 15 days more to current date in Joomla excluding Sat and Sun.

I added it with following code:

```
JFactory::getDate()->modify('+15 days');
```

But it doesn't exclude Saturday and Sunday. Any idea how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the following if you want to add 15 **working/business** days:

```
$date     = JFactory::getDate();
$newDate  = new JDate($date . ' +15 Weekday');  
$toFormat = $newDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Today is the 24th April 2015, so `$date` (excluding the time), will output the following:

```
2015-04-24
```

and `$toFormat` will output the following:

```
2015-05-15
```

Comment: Glad it helped :)